# Adding Code of missing functions in frama-c

Tags: frama-c, program-slicing

Forgive my ignorance. I need to do calculate backward slices for a project. After some searching, I came across frama-c. I downloaded the package on my ubuntu system which got me Frama-c Version: Fluorine-20130601. I am trying to use it for the first time. When finding out the undefined functions in my project almost all library functions are undefined, even printf, scanf etc(Neither code nor specification for function printf). According to the tutorial, I have to add stubs for all the undefined functions. Do I really have to add code for every library function that I am using even printf? Please guide.

Comment: First of all, this version is very old! You should rather use the last version Frama-C 15 Phosphorus. Have a look at http://frama-c.com/download.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to Frama-C Phosphorus, which brings tons of improvements regarding Variadic functions. In particular, specifications are automatically generated for printf/scanf-like functions when they are called on a constant format string. For non-variadic functions, some basic implementations are available in the directory `$FRAMA_C_INSTALL/share/libc/*.c` (in recent releases of Frama-C).

Comment: Thanks managed to install frama-c Aluminium version. The number of undefined functions drastically reduced. (Sorry I don't have enough credits to accept the answer)

Comment: Actually, as the person who asked the question, you can always accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Also, please note that support for variadic function was missing in Aluminium. Full support can only be found in Phosphorus.

Comment: Yes, but earlier I was'nt allowed to do so ...because my reputation was too low !

Comment: With OPAM the latest version I can get installed is Aluminium. For Phosphorus i guess I need to build from source...don't want to do that.

Comment: Frama-C Phosphorus has landed in Opam last week. Did you perform `opam update` before trying to upgrade?

Comment: I did. Some packages are updated but frama-c is just recompiled.