# Installing frama-c on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, frama-c, opam

I am trying to install frama-c on ubuntu following the directions here http://frama-c.com/download.html, after installing all the necessary packages, and giving the final command `opam install -j 1 frama-c`, the result is

```
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install conf-gtksourceview 2             [required by frama-c]
  ∗  install conf-gnomecanvas   2             [required by frama-c]
  ∗  install conf-gmp           1             [required by zarith]
  ∗  install lablgtk            2.18.5        [required by frama-c]
  ∗  install zarith             1.2           [required by frama-c]
  ∗  install ocamlgraph         1.8.6         [required by frama-c-base]
  ∗  install altgr-ergo         1.01          [required by frama-c]
       This release is too old. Please consider using version 1.30 that fixes many soundness bugs and brings a lot of improvements
  ∗  install alt-ergo           1.01          [required by frama-c]
       This release is too old. Please consider using version 1.30 that fixes many soundness bugs and brings a lot of improvements
  ∗  install frama-c-base       20160502      [required by frama-c]
       Why3 can be used by the WP plug-in for running additional automatic solvers
       Coq can be used with the WP plug-in for proving interactively proof obligations
  ∗  install frama-c            20160502
===== ∗  10 =====
Do you want to continue ? [Y/n] Y

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[alt-ergo] Archive in cache
[altgr-ergo] Archive in cache
[frama-c-base] Archive in cache
[lablgtk] Archive in cache
[ocamlgraph] Archive in cache
[zarith] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
∗  installed conf-gmp.1
∗  installed conf-gnomecanvas.2
∗  installed conf-gtksourceview.2
∗  installed lablgtk.2.18.5
∗  installed ocamlgraph.1.8.6
∗  installed zarith.1.2
∗  installed alt-ergo.1.01
∗  installed altgr-ergo.1.01
∗  installed frama-c-base.20160502
∗  installed frama-c.20160502
Done.
```

Apparently it is installed, but I cannot find it anywhere on my system, where it could be?

Comment: Just note that the Frama-C 15 (Phosphorus) release is not available in OPAM *right now*, but should be in a few minutes/hours. In case you'd like a *really* fresh installation... (doing `opam update && opam upgrade` then should be enough to get the new version, once it will be on the OPAM repository)

Comment: I am not looking for the latest version. I am just wanting to install the available version in opam.

Comment: One of the advantages of the latest version (Phosphorus) related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321758) is that the Variadic plug-in is now enabled by default, which should help dealing with variadic functions such as `printf`/`scanf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have OPAM set up correctly, the `frama-c` binary should be in your path. You can call it by just running `frama-c` or `frama-c-gui`.

You can use the `which` tool to find the actual path to the executable:

```
$ which frama-c
/home/isabelle/.opam/system/bin/frama-c
```

This `.opam/system/bin` directory is where OPAM installs all of its programs by default.

Comment: Yes that's the first thing anybody would be do. Using frama-c command on CLI returns: The program 'frama-c' is currently not installed. As far as opam is considered 'which opam' gives me /usr/local/bin/opam. How can I know that opam is correctly set up or not.

Comment: ok. I got it. Apparently .opam directory was hidden, so I could'nt view it in the directory list. frama-c could also only be accessed inside the .opam directory path. Thanks

Comment: In that case, it seems like you do *not* have OPAM set up correctly. When you install OPAM, it asks you if it may modify your `.profile` to add that path to your `PATH` variable. That takes effect the next time you log out and back in. Until then, it also tells you what command to run to set up your environment without logging out.